# Should I use a React Component if it always renders null, or just use a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a UI and came across something that made me wonder. I made a general re-usable function that fetches data and returns it in a callback, which is given to the function by whatever is calling that function. But that's all it does, it fetches data and passes it onward. At the moment the function can take up to ~15 different parameters/props.

I made it a React Component at first, due to the feasibility of calling the function like so:

```html
<SomeFunction 
  param1={some_param_1}
  param2={some_param_2}
  ...
/>
```

This way I can easily add and omit parameters at will. However, the `SomeFunction` always returns `null`, as its main point is returning fetched data in a callback. Should this Component be reverted to a simple function without any React in it? If so, what is the best way to approach the parameters?

My mind can quickly come up with two alternatives, the first one being positional arguments:

```
function someFunction(param1, param2, ... param15)
```

But this seems like a stretch, as I need to give many nulls or such if I want to pass something as the 15th parameter.

Another way that came to mind is to use an object:

```
function someFunction(options)
```

and then access parameters like `options.param1` and `options.param2`.

---

Is the Component approach or the function approach better in this type of case? And what is the best way to handle gazillion optional parameters to a function in JS? I'm not a total noob but it feels like there are so many ways to approach things and best practices in the JS world, not to mention the ever-changing nature of the language and its derivatives.

Comment: Function would be lighter because it takes away need for unnecessary features. Also in answer to your question - how to handlea gazillion parameters? Don't go above 7. Try to aim for less than 4.  Break onto smaller functions that reduce complexity. Just think the more parameters the more permutations the harder to reason with. This is why high iq types who program at genius level no one else can work with their code because they do not consider other people of limited thinking capacity. Code to empower others not to discriminate them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. Make it a normal function that accepts its parameters as an object, probably using destructuring. (A component receives its props as an object, so that's basically the same thing.)
2. Return a promise rather than passing in a callback. Promises provide standard semantics that can be consumed with `await` in an `async` function and/or combined with the various promise combinators (`Promise.all`, `Promise.race`, etc.).

So for instance, if your function currently uses something that provides a promise (like `fetch`):

```
async function fetchTheInformation({param1, param2, param3 = "default for param3"}) {
    const response = await fetch(/*...*/);
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
    }
    return response.appropriateMethodHere(); // .text(), .json(), .arrayBuffer(), etc.
}
```

if it doesn't use something that provides a promise:

```
function fetchTheInformation({param1, param2, param3 = "default for param3"}) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // ...start the operation and call `resolve` if it works, `reject` with an `Error` if it doesn't...
    });
}
```

In either case, the call to it can look like this in an `async` function:

```
const information = await fetchTheInformation({
    param1: "parameter 1",
    param2, // <=== If you happen to have `param2` in a variable/constant with the same name, no need to repeat it
});
```

*(errors [rejections] will automatically propagate to the caller of the `async` function to be handled there)*

or in a non-`async` function:

```
fetchTheInformation({
    param1: "parameter 1",
    param2, // <=== If you happen to have `param2` in a variable/constant with the same name, no need to repeat it, this is just like `param2: param,`
})
.then(information => {
    // ...use the information...
})
.catch(error => {          // Or return the promise chain to something else that will handle errors
    // ...handle/report error...
});
```

---

About the parameter list: I assume at least one parameter is required, but if they're **all** optional (have reasonable defaults), you can do the list like this:

```
function example({a = "default for a", b = "default for b", c = "default for c"} = {}) {
}
```

The expressions after `=` within the destructuring provide defaults for those destructured parameters. The `= {}` at the end makes the entire parameters object optional, you with the above you can do `example()` or `example({})` or `example({a: "something"})`, etc.

Comment: *(FWIW, I got into destructuring, including parameter destructuring, in Chapter 7 of my recent book* JavaScript: The New Toys. *Links in my profile if you're interested.)*